# Angular JS / radio button / value / result

Tags: angularjs

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bigbiff02/uNFWW/ shows how to get the selected object using radio buttons and ng-repeat.

I´m doing it the same way, but getting some "\" in my selected object/result.
The array will be populated correctly (SQlite result ...)

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type="radio" name="it" ng-model="$parent.selectedItem" value="{{item}}" />
...


{{selectedItem | json }}

// Here is the problem!?                
"{\"id:\":\"test\", ...
```

Does anybody know the reason why?

**UPDATE:** function in service which gets the result from the SQL query and data-binding in controller

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
// SERVICE
var items = [];
for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
var row = results.rows.item(i);                   
picoSys.push(row);                          
}
deferred.resolve(items);

// CONTROLLER
...
$scope.items = items;
...
```

Comment: The double quotes, which is required for JSON, are being escaped, likely by SQlite. Where are you getting the object/result from? Is that what is being stored into your SQlite db?

Comment: The "\" is to escape double-quotes in the double-quoted string, it's not a problem at all.

Comment: It looks like items is an array of strings rather than being an array of objects.

Comment: ok, i think it´s really an array of strings ... but how to get such "object"? or how to convert it?  don´t get the selected object/value with $scope.test = selectedItem ...

Comment: JSON.parse(...) did it for me!